# Wrong position of google adsense consent. Web pages with javascript apps keep crashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

google adsense consent keep crashing my pages with javascript apps. Definitely, the cookie consent is causing this problem. I just checked the website through a VPN service with location outside of European Union countries and there is no problem with javascript apps.

[Sticky position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyNXy.jpg)
[Bottom page position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4gBr.jpg)

I noticed one more thing.
Check the shared images.

- When the consent is loaded in a sticky position on the left side of the browser window (as it should be) then everything works fine.
- But if the consent is placed at the bottom of the page then the website keeps crashing

- I tried to update jquery.min.js version to v3.7.0 and jquery.form to 4.3.0 and it didn't solve this issue.